# Alexa sends SessionEndedRequest on timeout then displays error card to user

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

While testing my skill, if I do not reply and it times out, Alexa sends a SessionEndedRequest to my Lambda function.

Based on these docs: [Handle Requests Sent by Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html#sessionendedrequest):

> Your service cannot send back a response to a SessionEndedRequest.

Therefore, I am not responding to these requests.

But then my app shows a card with this message:

> **Skill response was marked as failure**
> (Skill Name)
>
> Request Identifier: amzn1.echo-api.request.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> The target Lambda application returned a failure response

So what should we handle this request that does not give a response, and does not result in this error?

I use Node.js in Lambda, but a Python answer is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the error in the card was for `SessionEndedRequest` only?

Generally, even if you send a response back to Alexa for a `SessionEndedRequest`, it won't be spoken.

You can handle a `SessionEndedRequest` like this in ask-nodejs-sdk-v2.

```
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    console.log("Inside SessionEndedRequestHandler");
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${JSON.stringify(handlerInput.requestEnvelope)}`);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};
```

Comment: That worked, I think because I was not responding at all, caused Lambda to error instead of ending the cycle properly. I thought providing a response would cause its own error because of the docs, but turns out the response is not spoken as you said and Lambda is happy to return something.

Comment: One use case is it to persist sessionAttributes. As the name suggests you can use it to do things that are required at the end of a user session.

Comment: omg I think you just pointed out the exact reason why my sessionAttributes are getting dropped! For a side note, that was EXTREMELY valuable, thank you!